JPA dynamic update query with non primary key
I have a Customer DAO where I have to update only specific fields based on input from the API in which where clause is a non primary key.
  UPDATE Customers SET ContactName = 'Alfred Schmidt', City= 'Frankfurt' WHERE location = 'PA';
The values may differ based on request but where clause will be the same which can return multiple entries as it is not unique.
What can be used here, I have JPA model and repository in place where general queries findBy findAll etc exists.But not sure on how this update query can be added dynamically may be using Criteria. Can someone please suggest?
I tried using SpringBeanUtils to copy the older value, but since there can be multiple updates it is not working

You can make partial update requests using JPA like this -
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Customer c SET c.contactName = :contactName, c.city = :city WHERE location = 'PA'")
    void updateContactAndCity(@Param("contactName") String contactName, @Param("city") String city);
}


I recommend to write method with Modifying Queries:
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
   @Modifying
   @Query("update Customer c set c.contactName = :contactName, c.city = :city where c.location = 'PA'")
   int updateContactNameAndCityWhereLocationPA(@Param("contactName") String contactName, @Param("city") String city);
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This will help only if we are sure of updating fields, because in my case it will not be just the contact name and city. It will be purely based on request
